# Text appears Dimmed

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Why do text appears dimmed in Visual Studio? is it possible to change this behavior?

[image: example]

Comment: It is dimmed when there's an #if around this code and the tested condition isn't true.  Define macros with Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > "Preprocessor definitions" setting.

Comment: OK! thank you, so this is actually working in real time.